# repeat wordpress code

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I set a piece of code to a function in WordPress and then call that function...this was my first guess, but of course this doesn't work...

Could someone suggest how I can get this to work so I can avoid redundant code. Also if I define code in a function can I call it in different .php files, or can I only call it within that file?

```
<?php
// This code will never change.
    function $test {
        echo('test this will be a long string and repeated many times.')
    }
?>

<?php
    echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: [PHP Manual: User-Defined functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP function names (unlike variables) are declared without dollar signs:

```
function test (
```

To call a function, use this format:

```
test();
```

Your code example will look like this:

```
<?php
// This code will never change.
    function test {
        echo('test this will be a long string and repeated many times.')
    }
?>

<?php
    test();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, will accept your answer as soon as poss!

Comment: Also if it is used in a theme be sure to put functions in function.php